# Unusual multiple website setup on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: iis, subdomain, windows-server-2012-r2

I currently have the following website setup on Windows Server 2012 R2. The following website is catching all the traffic to the webserver and then adding a few URL rewrite rules, such as forcing HTTPS and appending www.

[image]

I want to add a second website under a subdomain of the above site and diferent source code. How do I go about it?

EDIT: I've created a second website with a binding to the subdomain but all traffic is being redirected to the first website, as setup above. Does the first website require a defined Host Name? If so, that's not possible because the code of the website above is handling about 100 domains. The content is loaded based on domain name. So probably adding a subdomain of one of the websites is not possible. Is someone able to clarify, please?

Comment: Create another site and assign proper site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: The tutorial doesn't explain how to setup a subdomain. In the example, I don't quite understand what `bindingInformation="*:80:lextudio.com"` does and how it doesn't conflict with the first website setup. I'd like to do this in IIS UI if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new website in IIS for example hostname site1.yourdomain.com and set the bindings and and point to website folder.

create a 2e website with hostname site2.yourdomain.com set bindings, and point to your 2e website folder.

and you can have a main site with hostname www.yourdomain.com or yourdomain.com

also set an ip if you want to bind to a specific ip only.

it is important to set the hostname.

Comment: I am familiar with how to create websites and bindings. The issue is that I aleady have a website that has an empty Host Name and must remain empty. The challenge is how do I setup a second website as all traffic is captured by the first one. `also set an ip if you want to bind to a specific ip only.` How? Why?